# Problems with a ListView

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I make a application in flutter.
It's simple. In the principal layout exist an stack. In the first level are a background (what its a simple gradient), and in the second lever are the "body" of the application.

In this body of application i have a column (To put one item below another). this column are divided by separate widgets. One is for the "tile", and other is for a ListView, this ListView will show information from a database, but in this moment i only create 10 items for an example.

The code is this:

```
//This for a homepage
    @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return SafeArea(
          child: Scaffold(
            body: Stack(
              children: [
                Background(),
                HomeBody(),
              ],
            ),
    );
```

The background (are in another file, in the homepage are imported):

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
        begin: Alignment.topCenter,
        end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        stops: [0.2, 0.8],
        colors: [
          Color(0xff2E305F),
          Color(0xff202333),
        ],
      )),
    );
```

And this is the "body":

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          PageTitle(),
          Changes(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PageTitle extends StatelessWidget {
  const PageTitle({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 25,
            ),
            Text(
              'Biggest Title',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 55.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
                //height: 1,
                ),
            Text(
              'low subtitle',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 14.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Changes extends StatelessWidget {
  const Changes({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      children: [
        Text('Text0'),
        Text('Text0'),
        Text('Text0'),
        Text('Text0'),
        Text('Text0'),
        Text('Text0'),
        Text('Text0'),
        Text('Text0'),
        Text('Text0'),
        Text('Text0'),
        Text('Text0'),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

The error is:

```
═══════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown during performResize():
Vertical viewport was given unbounded height.

Viewports expand in the scrolling direction to fill their container. In this case, a vertical viewport was given an unlimited amount of vertical space in which to expand. This situation typically happens when a scrollable widget is nested inside another scrollable widget.

If this widget is always nested in a scrollable widget there is no need to use a viewport because there will always be enough vertical space for the children. In this case, consider using a Column instead. Otherwise, consider using the "shrinkWrap" property (or a ShrinkWrappingViewport) to size the height of the viewport to the sum of the heights of its children.
The relevant error-causing widget was
ListView
lib/widgets/home_body_screen.dart:64
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      RenderViewport.computeDryLayout.<anonymous closure>
package:flutter/…/rendering/viewport.dart:1369
#1      RenderViewport.computeDryLayout
package:flutter/…/rendering/viewport.dart:1430
#2      RenderBox.performResize
package:flutter/…/rendering/box.dart:2332
#3      RenderObject.layout
package:flutter/…/rendering/object.dart:1758
#4      RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout
package:flutter/…/rendering/proxy_box.dart:116
...
The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderViewport#33c99 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
RenderObject: RenderViewport#33c99 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

    offset: ScrollPositionWithSingleContext#b9cb0(offset: 0.0, range: null..null, viewport: null, ScrollableState, AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics -> ClampingScrollPhysics -> RangeMaintainingScrollPhysics, IdleScrollActivity#03740, ScrollDirection.idle)
    anchor: 0.0
    center child: RenderSliverPadding#e0507 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
        parentData: paintOffset=Offset(0.0, 0.0)
        constraints: MISSING
        geometry: null
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero
        textDirection: ltr
        child: RenderSliverList#2982b NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
            parentData: paintOffset=Offset(0.0, 0.0)
            constraints: MISSING
            geometry: null
            no children current live
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderViewport#33c99 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1930 pos 12: 'hasSize'

The relevant error-causing widget was
ListView
lib/widgets/home_body_screen.dart:64
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderViewport#33c99 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1930 pos 12: 'hasSize'

The relevant error-causing widget was
ListView
lib/widgets/home_body_screen.dart:64
```

I'm a newest in flutter, i understand some things, but not all.
My opinion is: "this error is caused by her possition, yeah, its scrollable but he does not know where ends". Sorry if i wrong.

thanks all!

Comment: use ```shrinkWrap: true``` for the ```ListView```

Comment: Wow, amazing!. This is the answer. But why doesn't it scroll?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use `ListView` inner `SingleChildScrollView`, you need to disable scrolling property of `ListView`.

```
ListView(
    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    shrinkWrap: true,
    primary: false,
    children: []
)
```

Comment: Okay okay. Thats work well. Thank you men.
What can I use to replace SingleChildScrollView?

Comment: You can use both. I mean ListView and SingleChildView have his own scrolling properties, so To use them together, you need to disable ListView's scrolling property.